# In JQuery, how do I add an onload or init even to an object?

Tags: jquery

I'd like to have a select box control display / hiding of sections in a form

First, I added an .change event on the item, and this works if I actually change the item

```
$('#mySelect').change(
       function() {
            updateSections($(this));
       });
```

Then all I wanted is to have the `.change` event be called at least once, when the page is loaded

The only way I could think of is in `$(document).ready` which seems like a detached location

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    updateSections($('#mySelect'));

}
```

The main issue is that I don't have the ID of the item from where I write the function (generated code)

So I would like to do something like this (conceptional code), and don't know if there is any way to do it

```
$('#mySelect').change(
       function() {
            updateSections($(this));
       }).init(
       function() {
            updateSections($(this));
       });
```

`.load()` only works on `a` / `img` tags

Also from a design perspective, the onDraw of an item is a standard event in any UI framework, and having one event directly on the object, and one on the document looks weird to me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

jQuery will allow you to just call the `.change()` method on load. You might do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#mySelect').change(function() {
        updateSections($(this));
    });

    $('#mySelect').change();
});
```

You can probably put `.change()` after the first `$('#mySelect')` occurrence for brevity, but I wanted to be verbose; the `$('#mySelect').change();` will fire the defined `.change()` event on the select box.

Answer (score 0):

I would make UpdateSections a jQuery plugin. Follow this simple tutorial, or google for a more in depth one.

http://blog.jeremymartin.name/2008/02/building-your-first-jquery-plugin-that.html

Then you'd end up with something like this. You can act directly on the object.

```
$('#mySelect').change(function(){
    $(this).updateSelections();
}).updateSelections();
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be an use case for a plugin.